# LyX's Hollywood document class

Tags: spacing, lyx

I'm experimenting with A4 PDF outputs and have encountered the following issues:

- With default margins some text is clipped, i.e. text that would follow the bottom of one page doesn't appear at the top of the next one. I can fix this with non-default margins, but I don't know if there are recommended choices for these.
- My main concern, however, is the fact that each new scene starts on a new page, unless it's short enough to fit on the current page. Can I use the LaTeX preamble to change this behaviour so that scenes always, or never, start a new page?
- A less important question I have is whether Scene titles can be made to appear in bold, again with some preamble edit.

`hollywood.cls` is available from https://www.lyx.org/trac/browser/lyxgit/lib/tex (GitHub clone: https://github.com/nicowilliams/lyx/tree/master/lib/tex)

Minimal example:

```
#LyX 2.2 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 508
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass hollywood
\begin_preamble
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\end_preamble
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language british
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize a4paper
\use_geometry true
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\topmargin 2.5cm
\bottommargin 2.5cm
\footskip 1cm
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle fancy
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Scene
\noindent
Scene
\end_layout

\begin_layout Description
\noindent
Description
\end_layout

\begin_layout Dialogue
\noindent
Character 1: Dialogue
\end_layout

\begin_layout Dialogue
Character 2: When the next scene starts, it'll be on this page because it's
 short enough to fit.
\end_layout

\begin_layout Scene
\noindent
Scene 2
\end_layout

\begin_layout Dialogue
Character 2: By contrast, the next scene is so long it won't fit on this
 page, so it starts on the next one.
\end_layout

\begin_layout Scene
\noindent
Scene 3
\end_layout

\begin_layout Dialogue
Character 2: Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem
 accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab
 illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
 Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit,
 sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.
 Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur,
 adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore
 et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.
 Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit
 laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum
 iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae
 consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
\end_layout

\begin_layout Dialogue
Character 1: Why are you saying all that?
\end_layout

\begin_layout Dialogue
Character 2: Well, it's based on a Roman-
\end_layout

\begin_layout Dialogue
Character 1: I know what lorem ipsum is.
 I mean, why are you quoting so much of it? Are you stalling?
\end_layout

\begin_layout Dialogue
Character 2: As aforementioned, this scene has to be long to demonstrate
 how page breaks work in this implementation of the Hollywood document class.
\end_layout

\begin_layout Dialogue
Character 1: Said when?
\end_layout

\begin_layout Dialogue
Character 2: Oh, that's right; you weren't in the last scene.
\end_layout

\begin_layout Description
\noindent
Character 1 reads the script's description of Scene 1.
\end_layout

\begin_layout Dialogue
Character 1: You definitely never mentioned this was about demonstrated
 what's going on with that document class.
\end_layout

\begin_layout Dialogue
Character 2: Well, I'll give you that.
\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Comment: Seeing as that class is not available on [CTAN](https://ctan.org/search/?phrase=hollywood), can you post a link to it? Without access to the class, it's not possible to answer your question(s). Edit: And a minimal working example would also be appreciated. (see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4488 and https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I don't know how to link to classes; it's just one of the classes that came with my copy of LyX. It's classified as a Script document class.

Comment: Right, I see that it's something included in the LyX-package for Mac.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thanks for the edit. It's odd, because I'm running Windows.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood something, or maybe it's been added to the Windows-bundle as well.

Comment: Anyways, can you make a minimal example, i.e. a small document with some dummy text, that demonstrates the problems you're describing? A lot easier to give useful information if one doesn't have to first figure out how the class works, and then guess at how you/LyX does things.

Comment: What's the best way to share files? For some reason, my Google Drive won't let me upload this LyX file.

Comment: A `.lyx` file is a plain text file, open it in e.g. Notepad and copy-paste the whole thing directly into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the first issue you refer to, but for the second two I think the following addition to the LaTeX Preamble in the Document settings will do, in order to make scenes start on the same page:

```
\renewcommand{\scene}[1]%
{\vspace{4bp}
\raggedright
\par
{\bfseries\uppercase{#1}}
}%
```

The first page will then look like this:

[image: top of first page of output]

If you instead want each scene to start on a new page, try

```
\renewcommand{\scene}[1]%
{\clearpage
{\bfseries\uppercase{#1}}
}%
```

Example `.lyx` file:

```
#LyX 2.2 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 508
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass hollywood
\begin_preamble
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{}
\cfoot{\thepage}


\renewcommand{\scene}[1]%
{\vspace{4bp}
\raggedright
\par
{\bfseries\uppercase{#1}}
}%


% this will make each scene start on a new page
%\renewcommand{\scene}[1]%
%{\clearpage
%{\bfseries\uppercase{#1}}
%}%


#LyX 2.2 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 508
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass hollywood
\begin_preamble
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{}
\cfoot{\thepage}


\renewcommand{\scene}[1]%
{\vspace{4bp}
\raggedright
\par
{\bfseries\uppercase{#1}}
}%


% this will make each scene start on a new page
%\renewcommand{\scene}[1]%
%{\clearpage
%{\bfseries\uppercase{#1}}
%}%
\end_preamble
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language british
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize a4paper
\use_geometry true
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\topmargin 2.5cm
\bottommargin 2.5cm
\footskip 1cm
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle fancy
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Scene
\noindent
Scene
\end_layout

\begin_layout Description
\noindent
Description
\end_layout

\begin_layout Dialogue
\noindent
Character 1: Dialogue
\end_layout

\begin_layout Dialogue
Character 2: When the next scene starts, it'll be on this page because it's
 short enough to fit.
\end_layout

\begin_layout Scene
\noindent
Scene 2
\end_layout

\begin_layout Dialogue
Character 2: By contrast, the next scene is so long it won't fit on this
 page, so it starts on the next one.
\end_layout

\begin_layout Scene
\noindent
Scene 3
\end_layout

\begin_layout Dialogue
Character 2: Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem
 accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab
 illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
 Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit,
 sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.
 Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur,
 adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore
 et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.
 Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit
 laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum
 iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae
 consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?
\end_layout

\begin_layout Dialogue
Character 1: Why are you saying all that?
\end_layout

\begin_layout Dialogue
Character 2: Well, it's based on a Roman-
\end_layout

\begin_layout Dialogue
Character 1: I know what lorem ipsum is.
 I mean, why are you quoting so much of it? Are you stalling?
\end_layout

\begin_layout Dialogue
Character 2: As aforementioned, this scene has to be long to demonstrate
 how page breaks work in this implementation of the Hollywood document class.
\end_layout

\begin_layout Dialogue
Character 1: Said when?
\end_layout

\begin_layout Dialogue
Character 2: Oh, that's right; you weren't in the last scene.
\end_layout

\begin_layout Description
\noindent
Character 1 reads the script's description of Scene 1.
\end_layout

\begin_layout Dialogue
Character 1: You definitely never mentioned this was about demonstrated
 what's going on with that document class.
\end_layout

\begin_layout Dialogue
Character 2: Well, I'll give you that.
\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```